# .htaccess RewriteRule(s) not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to learn how to use RewriteRule.

I have 2 'pages' (wordpress)-
`domain.com/webinars/` (shows list of all webinars)
and
`domain.com/webinar/` (shows specific webinar details)

I have trying to set the following conditions -

(1) `domain.com/webinars/{Year}/{Month}/` will load `/webinar/?year={Year}&month={Month}`

(2) `domain.com/webinar/` (with no `/{Year}/{Month}`) will load `/webinars/`

(3) `domain.com/webinar/?year={Year}&month={Month}` will redirect to `/webinars/{Year}/{Month}/` and then apply condition #1

This is my attempted code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/webinars/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ /webinar/?year=$1&month=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^/webinar/$ /webinars/

RewriteRule ^/webinar/year=(\d+)$month=([\w-]+)$ /webinars/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Condition #1 results in a 404 page not found

Condition #2 shows `/webinar/` and not `/webinars/`

Condition #3 stays on `domain.com/webinar/?year={Year}&month={Month}` and does not redirect

What am I doing wrong? Only other code in my htaccess file is the default wordpress block.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^webinars/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /webinar/?year=$1&month=$2 [NC]
```

The rest could be done the same way .

Comment: No change. What is the difference between `([0-9]+)`/`([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and `([^/]+)`?

Comment: @Sean `([^/]+)` means any character not matching `/` , at least one .

Comment: @Sean I tried it and it seems to be working , try to test the first rule only as there might be a conflict with the rules . https://pasteboard.co/HsGX4xR.png

Comment: hmm... I have removed the other 2 rules, and have tried it both before and after the wordpress code block. still getting a 404 not found

Comment: My suggestion is to check if there's any other htaccess file somewhere else . Also please double check if you put your htaccess file in the root . Finally please review the server log to see what's the 404 path you are being redirected to .

Comment: no other `.htaccess` files on the site. it is in my root (httpdocs). Log is `404 GET /webinars/2018/May/ HTTP/1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rules,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webinar$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^year=([^/]+)&month=([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/webinars/%1/%2/? [R=302]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webinars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$
RewriteRule ^ webinar/?year=%1&month=%2 [L,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webinar/$
RewriteRule ^ webinars/ [L]
```

Comment: unfortunately no change as well. still getting `404 GET /webinars/2018/May/ HTTP/1.0` in logs and in the browser

Comment: what happen if you use directly webinar/?year=2018&month=May is it working fine?

Comment: yes, `https://example.com/webinar/?year=2018&month=May` loads correctly, as does `https://example.com/webinars/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on
# if /webinar/ is requested skip the rules and serve /webinar/ directory
RewriteRule ^webinar/?$ -  [L]
#redirect /webinar/?year={year}&month={month}
#To /webinar/year/month
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /webinar/\?year=([^\s&]+)&month=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /webinar/%1/%2? [L,R]
# rewrite new url to the old one
RewriteRule ^webinar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /webinar/?year=$1&month=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: getting a `500 [core:alert]  RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '/webinar/\\?year=([^\\s&]+)&month=([^\\s&)'`.

Comment: unfortunately no change. going to sleep on this, and see if I can figure it out in the morning. thanks for your help